# Python iterate over an async generator that yields a list

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a quite common pattern of fetching a page of content and paginating over it. There may be better libraries for this but, I'm new to Python and am trying to learn about how to use generators for this purpose.

In the below code, I would like to iterate over an async generator that yields a collection of items using a single for loop.

```
import asyncio

async def rest_api_list(after):
  after = 0 if after is None else after
  return iter(range(after, after + 3, 1)), (after + 3 if after <= 24 else None)

async def page_items():
  after = None
  while True:
    items, after = await rest_api_list(after)
    yield items
    if after == None:
      break

async def main():
  async for items in page_items():
    # ---> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! not elegant to loop twice here
    for item in items:
      print(item)

asyncio.run(main())
```

One easy fix seems to be to change from:

```
    yield items
```

into

```
    for item in items:
      yield item
```

but it doesn't feel the most python-ish way of doing it. Are there better approaches around this?

Comment: The only reason it seems inelegant is you have bad variable names. If you want to be able to treat all the items as the same, regardless of page, then your "fix" is a fix in the sense that it does what you want. So use it.

Comment: That's exactly the way to do it. With a regular generator you'd be able to write `yield from items`, but that's not yet supported for async generators (and likely will never be).